# Makeindex - Is it possible to set page numbers on the right border instead of using the comma delimiter?

Tags: formatting, indexing, makeindex

I'm creating an index using the `makeidx` package, and would like to change the default behavior:

> key, number

to something like:

> key ..................................................................................................... number

where "number is on the right border of the page, and the points could be spaces or points.

Currently I'm using a code similar to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=1]{idxlayout}
\makeindex

% more packages...

\begin{document}

Cover page

% index
\clearpage
\renewcommand\indexname{Table of Contents}
\printindex

\clearpage
Introduction
\index{Introduction}

\clearpage
Document body

\end{document}
```

The included files have call to index as usual: eg. `\index{1. Introduction}`. The file is compiled with makeindex and pdflatex.

But I have no idea on how to make improvements or this, nor I have found similar questions posted on this topic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As it stands, you may not get much attention as your code can't simply be copied and pasted into a file for testing since the included files are missing. You may find it simpler to just put a single `\index{test}` in your document and omit the `\include` instances. Alternatively, you can use the [`testidx` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/testidx), which is designed for testing index styles: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{makeidx}\usepackage{testidx} \makeindex \begin{document} \testidx \printindex \end{document}`. That makes it easier to test and propose a solution.

Comment: Are you using `\index` to simply create a table of contents? Is there any particular reason why you're not just using `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: I guess it's been a mixture of a translation problem and lack of experience with latex. I'm just reading [this website](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/table-of-contents/) and seems that `\tableofcontents` provides the desired behavior. I'll try it, and if you write it in the form of an answer I'll accept it ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, it's actually a table of contents, which can be simply be produced with `\tableofcontents`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
This is an introductory section.

\subsection{Sample Subsection}
This is a sample sub-section.

\end{document}
```

This doesn't require any external tools, just two instances of LaTeX (`pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`, as appropriate).

[image: image of document]

Here's a slightly longer example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Other}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}
This is the preface.

\mainmatter

\part{Sample Part}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is an introductory chapter.

\section{Sample section}
This is a sample section.

\subsection{Sample Subsection}
This is a sample sub-section.

\appendix
\chapter{Sample Appendix}
This is a sample appendix.

\chapter{Another Sample Appendix}
This is another sample appendix.

\end{document}
```

The table of contents now looks like:

[image: image of document]

This deals with all the numbering automatically. (`\frontmatter` switches to lower case Roman numerals for the page numbers and also suppresses the numbering of the section commands. `\mainmatter` switches back.)

If you were to use `\index`, makeindex would order alphabetically. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Ann Other}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\printindex

\chapter{Preface}\index{Preface}
This is the preface.

\mainmatter

\part{Sample Part}\index{I Sample Part}

\chapter{Introduction}\index{1 Introduction}
This is an introductory chapter.

\section{Sample section}\index{1.1 Sample section}
This is a sample section.

\subsection{Sample Subsection}\index{1.1.2 Sample subsection}
This is a sample sub-section.

\appendix
\chapter{Sample Appendix}\index{A Sample Appendix}
This is a sample appendix.

\chapter{Another Sample Appendix}\index{B Another Sample Appendix}
This is another sample appendix.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of index]

To answer your actual question of changing the separator between the indexed item and the corresponding number, you need to create a style file that changes the appropriate delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.ist}
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Test\index{test}\index{test!subitem}\index{test!subitem!subsubitem}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The call to `makeindex` now needs to include `-s` with the `.ist` file created by the `filecontents` environment. For example, if the document is called `myDoc.tex` then:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeindex -s myDoc.ist myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

[image: image of index]

The index defaults to 2 column format, which is why the dots don't span the entire page width. You may prefer to use `imakeidx` instead of `makeidx` to make it easier to customize.